# PHP stream context -> how to use in this scenario?

Tags: php, json, stream

I have a system that stores user comments in its own individual json file. I use scandir(); on the directory which gets all files and folders, but how do I limit it to json files, I don't want other files such as "." and ".." in the array because I need an accurate count.

I checked out the info on php.net but couldn't figure it out, perhaps you know of a resource you can point me toward, or which function to use.

Comment: Use a [FilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) mixed with a [FilesystemIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php). Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no stream context parameters that will help you filter out the types of files.

Assuming that your JSON files are saved with the `.json` extension, you just have to filter out the array based on the file extensions.

You can use [`readdir()`](http://php.net/readdir) to build a list of files, or simply loop over the results you get from `scandir` and create a new array from that.

Here is an example using `readdir`:

```
$files = array();
$dh = opendir($path);
while (($file = readdir($dh) !== false) {
    if (pathinfo($path . '/' . $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) !== 'json') continue;
    $files[] = $path . '/' . $file;
}

closedir($dh);

// $files now has an array of json files
```

Comment: Thanks Drew!
I ended up using
if(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)!=="json") continue;

Comment: to remove items from my scandir() array.

Answer (score 3):

This is a lovely example where the PHP library comes to the rescue.  `FilterIterator` is a class that you extend and override its accept method to use only the files you want. In this case we use a standard `FilesystemIterator` to iterate over a directory. You could also use a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` if you want to search for json files in sub-directories. This example iterates over json files in the current directory:

```
class StorageFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {

    function accept() {
        $item = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return $item->isFile() && $item->getExtension() === 'json';
    }

}

$storageFiles = new StorageFilterIterator(new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__));

foreach ($storageFiles as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

*`getExtension` exists in PHP >= 5.3.6*

---

Another lesser-known part of the Standard PHP Library (SPL) is [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php).  So if you want all of the items in an array instead of just iterating over them, you can do the following:

```
$storageFiles = iterator_to_array(
    new StorageFilterIterator(new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__))
);
```